# pytest - is there a way to ignore an autouse fixture?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, fixtures

I have this autouse fixture that will create a webdriver instance for each test:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def use_phantomjs(self):
    self.wd = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    yield
    self.close_wd()
```

However, some of our tests cannot run on PhantomJS due to a bug with one of our APIs. These tests can only run on Chrome (or Firefox), so I created another method for a webdriver instance using Chrome:

```
def use_chrome(self):
    self.wd = webdriver.Chrome()
```

which I plan to use on those tests, but I cannot get around the autouse fixture above.

Is there a way to somehow override the autouse fixture for some of our tests? I have tried using `pytest.mark.usefixtures` for each test but it doesn't seem ideal having to put that decorator on each and every test. Someone mentioned using metaclasses but I haven't fully understood how they work yet, so I was wondering if there was some other way that I might have missed.

Comment: thanks @saurabh baid, i have tried using the fixture on demand as you said below but it seems too repetitive and unnecessary having to put the fixture on each and every test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

----- UPDATE for latest versions of pytest-----
use `request.node.get_closest_marker()` to get the marker. Refer [get_closest_marker](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.nodes.Node.get_closest_marker)

---

You can achieve this in many ways , one way is to use the request fixture along with pytest mark fix.
All you need to do is, create a new generic fixture

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def browser(request):
    # _browser = request.node.get_marker('browser')
    _browser = request.node.get_closest_marker('browser')
    if _browser:
       if _browser.kwargs.get("use") == "chrome" :
            # Do chrome related setup
       elif _browser.kwargs.get("use") == "phantom" :
            # Do Phantom.js related setup
   else:
       # No mark up ,use default setup
```

and mark your tests like this

```py
@pytest.mark.browser(use="chrome")
def test_some_chrome_test():
    # browser here would return chrome driver

@pytest.mark.browser(use="phantom")
def test_some_phantomjs_test():
    # browser here would return phantom driver
```

Comment: thanks! will modify this abit and then will let you know if it works

Comment: glad it helped.

Comment: Glad it worked, but I think it would be simpler to just have two fixtures, `chrome_driver` and `phantom_driver`, and use those accordingly instead of marking each test accordingly. :) Also, pytest-selenium might be useful.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira the chrome_driver fixture is only temporary as we plan to remove it once the API with phantomjs issues is fixed :)

Comment: This does not work with pytest 5.4.1: `AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'get_marker'`.

Comment: It looks like I can use `request.node.get_closest_mark()` instead.

`get_marker()` was [removed in pytest 4.1.0](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#pytest-4-1-0-2019-01-05)

Answer (score -1):

There is way to use these function on demand without using `usefixtures` decorator like below.
If you have used `autouse=True` then it would be automatically called as per its scope and I dont think there is a way to skip that in any of the test.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=False)
def use_phantomjs(self):
    self.wd = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    yield
    self.close_wd()

def test_my_test(use_phantomjs):
 ...
 ...
```